# Websocket frame, TCP segment: the relationship?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, websocket

Websocket is high level protocol based on TCP.

Websocket has its own frame
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2

TCP also has its own segment:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

So, when using Websocket, send data:

1. First, the data is wrapped in Websocket frame,
2. then,  the frame is packed in TCP segments,
3. finally, send the TCP segments out.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You could have added

- the TCP segment is wrapped in an IP packet
- send the IP packet out